# Can I use 'commencement date' to describe the day I start to work in a company?

Tags: word-usage

From what I looked, 'commencement date' is a legal term, which means the starting date of a contract. http://thelawdictionary.org/commencement-date/

But I am interested to know that s it correct to write like this:

We have already discussed the **commencement/commencing date** of my employment and I am supposed to be on duty next Monday.

Or should I write '**starting date**' in this case? Thank you!

Comment: _Starting date_ would probably be the better term to use.

Comment: _Commencement_ has other connotations in English, most importantly referring to graduation from an educational institution.